# Get list of classes derived from given Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static-analysis

I wonder whether it is possible to get a list of classes derived from a given `Class`.

I see, there is a callback [`Class::inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Class.html#method-i-inherited), which is to be “invoked whenever a subclass of the current class is created.” There are two problems with this approach:

1. When I am not a producer of this class (that said, I have to monkeypatch it,) I can’t generally make sure that my monkeypatch would be applied before the first derived class is to be created.
2. In the perfect world, I would get the list of classes despite whether they were already initialized or not, while *a callback is to be called actually when the class is being instantiated*.

I understand, that RTTI is probably not the best way to retrieve the information I need (because of 2. above.) Would anybody suggest another approach? Static code analysis? Whatsoever?

I would really appreciate any ideas. Say, I have all the code of interest within my directory (in other words, I am interested in *my* classes, derived from some predefined Class only, e.g. `ApplicationController`s in my Rails app.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using TracePoint ? Let me know if the following code serves your purpose -

```
class DerivedClassObserver

  def initialize(classes)
    @classes, @subclasses = classes, {}
  end

  def start
    @trace_point = TracePoint.new(:class) do |tp|
      tp.self.ancestors.map do |ancestor|
        if ancestor != tp.self && @classes.include?(ancestor.name)
          (@subclasses[ancestor.name] ||= []) << tp.self.name
        end
      end
    end

    @trace_point.enable
  end

  def stop
    @trace_point.disable
  end

  def subclasses(class_name)
    @subclasses[class_name]
  end
end
```

## Example Usages

```
observer = DerivedClassObserver.new %w|A AA|
observer.start

# Borrowed example from @Cary
class A       ; end
class AA  < A ; end
class AB  < A ; end
class AC  < A ; end
class AAA < AA; end
class AAB < AA; end
class ABA < AB; end
class ABB < AB; end

observer.stop

puts "A subclasses #{observer.subclasses('A').join(', ')}"
# => A subclasses AA, AB, AC, AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB

puts "AA subclasses #{observer.subclasses('AA').join(', ')}"
# => AA subclasses AAA, AAB
```

Thanks

Comment: Upvote for giving me a notice about `TracePoint`, but this code unfortunately works (as the code in any other answer here) only when class loading mechanism is known and predictable. The latter is not a case in Rails, for instance.

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa I tried it with rails, here is my result - 

ActiveRecord::Base subclasses PaperTrail::Version, PaperTrail::VersionAssociation and All of my models... 

Just add it on the boot.rb

Comment: @mudasobwa so it should be working with unpredictable context if you can require this file before initializing rest of the files.

TracePoint works perfectly, it doesn't require any class initiation, just definition triggers :class event and so on. 

Let me know if you have any specific question which i might have skipped

Comment: Well, I finally came to more elegant solution postponing my actions to be taken on classes until the class is actually instantiated. And here your advise with `TracePoint` was geniously helpful, since `inherited` is called _before_ class initialization is done. So, I initialize tracing on `inherited` and apply my actions on `TracePoint.new(:end) do |tp| tp.self == myClazz ...`. I will manually award this answer, thank you very much. (AFAIU, to award a bounty I should wait until I can start a bounty and only than accept an answer, awarding the bounty. Stay tuned :))

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa :) glad that you liked TracePoint.

Comment: Awesome! Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ObjectSpace::each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object):

```
def derived_classes(klass)
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).with_object([]) { |k,a| a << k if k < klass }
end

class A       ; end
class AA  < A ; end
class AB  < A ; end
class AC  < A ; end
class AAA < AA; end
class AAB < AA; end
class ABA < AB; end
class ABB < AB; end

derived = derived_classes(A)
  #=> [AC, AA, AB, AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB]
```

**Edit:**

Alas, this is not what is needed, but let me offer a method that might be useful once the derived classes have been identified:

```
def order_classes(top, derived)
  children = derived.select { |k| k.superclass == top }
  return top if children.empty?   
  { top=>children.each_with_object([]) { |k,a|
    a << order_classes(k, derived-children) } }
end

order_classes(A, derived)
  #=> {A=>[AC, {AA=>[AAA, AAB]}, {AB=>[ABA, ABB]}]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won’t work for `B` until `class B < A ; end` is explicitly loaded. That said, this approach is exactly the same as to overload `Class::inherited` (but probably more greedy to resources.)

Comment: I forgot `inherited` applied to other than direct descendants. Thanks for the reminder. It's very hacky, and possibly unreliable, but could you parse the file as text? Could there be any other way to determine descendants before they are instantiated?

Comment: I have actually almost decided to go with parsing, since there is likely no way to retrieve this information in runtime. Anyway, thanks for your effort; the reminder about `ObjectSpace` saved me a lot of time on googling.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ApplicationController.subclasses
```

Comment: 1. You probably wanted to suggest `Class#descendants`, since I requested not to limit search to direct subclasses. 2. Almost every rails crap is actually nothing more than [syntax sugar](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb) — your answer is actually is a syntax sugar to @Cary’s answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class#< and ObjectSpace#each_object.

```
class A; end
class B < A; end
class C < A; end
class CC < C; end
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|c| c < A}
# => [C, B, CC]

class Class
  def subclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|c| c < self}
  end
end
A.subclasses
# => [C, B, CC]
```

I'm not sure how to name this, inferior_classes, subclasses, derived_classes, children_rec, descendants?

Comment: How you answer differs from @Cary’s answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution, applicable for tests:

```
def derived from
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/**/*.rb"].map do |f|
    File.read(f).match(/(\S+)\s*<\s*#{from}\s/) && $1  
  end.compact
end

▶ derived User
#⇒ [Admin, Editor]
```